# Calculate $P(X>a)$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with geometric distribution, $X \sim Geo(p)$, I need to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X>a)$.

I Know that $q=(1-p)$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=a)= p[(1-p)^a] = p(q^a)$

I've tried $\mathbb{P}(X>a) = 1-\mathbb{P}(X\le a)= 1-[\mathbb{P}(X=a)+\mathbb{P}(X<a)]$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbb{P}(X > a) = \sum\limits_{i=a+1}^{+\infty} \mathbb{P}(X = i) = \sum\limits_{i=a+1}^{+\infty}(1-p)^{i-1}p = p\sum\limits_{i=a+1}^{+\infty}(1-p)^{i-1} = p\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}(1-p)^{j+(a+1)-1}$$

$$ = p(1-p)^{a}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{+\infty}(1-p)^{j} =\frac{p(1-p)^{a}}{1-(1-p)} = (1-p)^{a}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$P(X \leq a) = 1 - (1-p)^a $$
And you have progressed correctly 
$$P(X>a) = 1 - p(X \leq a)$$
$$ = (1-p)^a$$